# Why does this insertionSort code not give the correct output?

Tags: java, sorting, insertion-sort

```
public class First{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] arr = new int[]{4, 2, 7, 8};
        int[] p = insertionSort(arr);
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(p));

    }

    public static int[] insertionSort(int[] arr){
        int key;
        int i;
        for (int j = 1; j < arr.length; j++){
            key = arr[j];
            i = j - 1;
            while( (i > 0) && (arr[i] > key)){
                arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
                i--;
            }
            arr[i + 1] = key;
        }
        return arr;
    }

}
```

I'm not sure what is going on, but the above code just prints the original unsorted array instead of the sorted int array.

Comment: Step through the flow with a debugger. Having somebody point out your mistake is not going to give you that amazing, rewarding feeling of finding your own bug.

Comment: i will give you a hint try to add some SOUT(system.out.println) for every important variable in your code on the loops then see by your self what your loop is doing by adding a sleep function with 1 seconde. that really helpful to see what is happening in real time (or debug finally is the same)

Comment: @MohammedHousseynTaleb - That's really the hard way to debug.  Learning to use a debugger, and stepping through the code, is much better and much less effort.  You can examine whatever variables you want to at any point you like, and use things like conditional breakpoints to stop the flow when a particular variable achieves a particular value.  Learning to use a debugger is an incredibly valuable skill for a programmer to master.  Using `println` and `sleep` - not so much.

Comment: @DavidWallace i m surely whit your point of view because i also use debugger but for an algorithmic view to create it own debugger by printing and sleeping help the (new) programmer to learn what he is doing while writing is only an exercise of mind . but you are right and i support your point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
while ((i > 0) && (arr[i] > key)) {
```

should be

```
while ((i >= 0) && (arr[i] > key)) {
```

then I get

```
[2, 4, 7, 8]
```